# What if we replace the DNA in stem cells with ours and we place the cells inside damaged organs to heal them?

Tags: technology, organ-damage, self-healing-repairing, stem-cells, dna

I don't know a lot about stem cells or if a person's DNA could affect them in such a manner that if a person would have a damaged limb or organ, it would make it grow back with stem cell treatment.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how stem cell transplants work?